# Заставить появиться клавиатуру в браузере

Tags: gwt, javascript, java

Есть приложение, написанное на GWT. Рассматривается случай, когда пользователь заходит с устройства с touch-интерфейсом. Нужно заставить появиться клавиатуру, когда фокус не стоит в поле редактирования (или подобном). Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу ошибаться, но предполагаю, что никак.

---

За появление клавиатуры отвечает приложение, в котором происходит отображение вашего `GWT-based` приложения, **т.е, в 99% случаев - браузер.** *Т.е, если браузер предполагает, что ввода не должно происходить, то он и не будет показывать эту клавиатуру.*

Можно, конечно, разместить какой-нибудь невидимый или сильно смещенный `input` и с помощью `js` кода переводить на него фокус, но не уверен, *насколько такое поведение коррелирует с тем, что вы хотите получить.*

Comment: Я попробовал использовать `div` со свойством `contenteditable`. В Android планшете работает, а в iPad - нет :(

Comment: @Trash Ну теперь, видимо, осталось придумать какой-нибудь такой же костыль для `Safari.`

Comment: `contenteditable` поддерживается, начиная с iOS 5. Вам пора сделать апдейт.